# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre un "switch" y un "if"?

Tags: javascript, condiciones, switch

Mi nombre es Alex y soy estudiante de ingeniería.
Me encuentro empezando la carrera y por ahora estoy viendo los fundamentos básicos de la programación. Sin embargo, esta semana me enseñaron acerca de los condicionales "if" y "switch". Y me dijeron que estos son diferentes pero que tiene prácticamente el mismo funcionamiento y, eso a mi me confundió un poco. Es por eso que quisiera saber cuál es la diferencia entre estos dos y que función especifica tiene cada uno.
Muchas gracias a los que me aclaren esta duda, feliz día.

Comment: Un "switch" es un caso especial del "if". Cualquier cosa que puedas hacer con "switch", también la puedes hacer con "if". Viceversa no funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

son muy similares, la gran diferencia, es que en el **switch** solo puedo evaluar el valor de una variable, y en los **if** puedo tener otro tipo de condiciones.
Ejemplo con **switch**:

```
let casa = "blanca";
let acto = "";

switch( casa ) {
    case: "blanca": acto = "matar presidente"; break;
    case: "rosada": acto = "matar presidente"; break;
    default: acto "dormir"; break;
}
```

Como puedes ver, siempre estoy modificando mis acciones, en base al valor de **casa**.
Veamos con **if**:

```
let casa = "blanca";
let acto = "";
let puede = true;

if( casa.length == 4 ) {
    acto = "matar al presidente";
}
else if( puede ) {
    acto = "matar al presidente";
}
else if( casa.localeCompare( "rosada" ) ) {
    acto = "matar al presidente";
}
```

En definitiva... siempre hay que mat... a no, perdón, el switch se puede pensar como un **if** limitado, espero haber despejado tu duda.

Comment: Python 3.10 tiene "match-case", que es como un switch y puede evaluar múltiples variables.

Comment: @CandidMoe, hola, y en javascript hay algo parecido?.

Comment: No me preguntes, que no se.

Comment: @CandidMoe, me has hecho reir!! entonces supongo que podemos eliminar los comentarios... si te parece!!

Comment: @MarcePuente reir de que?...

Comment: Hola @Cris223511.dev, creo que si lees los comentarios...

Answer (score 0):

Un switch tiene condiciones para ejecutar código, al igual que el if(), suelen tener la misma funcionalidad cuando utilizas un if con secuencias else if().
Ejemplo:

```
$manzana = "roja";
switch ($manzana) {
case "verde":
console.log("La manzana es verde");
[break;]
case "amarilla":
console.log("La manzana es amarilla");
[break;]
case "roja":
console.log("La manzana es roja");
[brek;]
default:
console.log("La manzana NO es verde, amarilla o roja");
[break;]
}
```

Ahora con if()

```
$manzana = "roja";
if($manzana == "verde"){
console.log("La manzana es verde");
} else if($manzana == "amarilla"){
console.log("La manzana es amarilla");
} else if($manzana == "roja"){
console.log("La manzana es roja");
} else {
console.log("La manzana NO es verde, amarilla o roja");
}
```

Ambos códigos tienen como resultado "La manzana es roja", espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu ejemplo me ayudo a reforzar y aclarar mas el concepto. Te agradezco. 